# Flow - Decision Outcome Still Execute When Condition Does Not Met

Tags: visual-workflow, salesforce-flow

I'm using Record-Triggered Flow.

First, I use Get Record to fetch Contact. After that, I use Decision with 2 outcomes:

1. Result from Get Record isNull = false (Contact is found)
2. Default outcome(Contact is not found)

I tested with 2nd condition that mean Contact is not found. Somehow, the 1st condition still execute and auto-assign to 1 Contact. I tried with different records but it keeps assign to that only Contact.

Thank you so much.

Debug Result:

```
Find all Contact records where

Phone Equals {!$Record.SuppliedPhone} (null)
Store the values of these fields in Get_Related_Contact: AccountId, Id
Result

Successfully found records.


Outcome executed: Yes
Outcome conditions

{!Get_Related_Contact} (Contact (0035i000009mNVtAAM)) Is null false
All conditions must be true (AND)
```

[image: Flow Debug Result]

Answer (score 1):

- Even if you will not find records in Get Records element it will not
  be null but empty array[]. Hence your condition 1 will always meet.

Workaround will be

```
Add Assignment: {!GetRecordsLength} Equals Count {!Get_Related_Contact} 
Add Decision: {!GetRecordsLength} Equals '0'
```

Comment: Hi @amitghadage, thank you for your solution. It works! However, I think the 2nd condition execute because we set Primary Contact of the Org so whenever a Contact is not found, the system auto-assign this Primary Contact. 

I also have another branch that fetch Order object with the same condition isNull = false => The No outcome works just fine.

I will research more on this, thank you for helping me out.